# Can't any value after linking an external component in react native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I am just experimenting with react-native to build a mobile application and I am very new to both react and react-native.So I am unable to figure-out this error I ran into :

This is my Card.js which I build for styling purpose:

```
import React from 'react'; import { View } from 'react-native';

const Card = (props) => {   return (
    <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
      {props.childern}
    </View>   ); };

const styles = {   containerStyle: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 2,
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: 1,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    marginTop: 10

  } };

export default Card;
```

Then I added Card component to my AlbumDetail.js for styling purpose.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text , View } from 'react-native';
import Card from './Card';


// Constant if class and function ins not used
const AlbumDetail = (props) => {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>{props.albumList.title}</Text>
        </View>
      );
};
// export
export default AlbumDetail;
```

Now the problem is :

## If I add

```
<Card></Cade>
```

it would only show style without datas are the visible

## If I keep

```
<View></View>
```

it would show all the data without style.

[Problem Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdqYl.png)

Comment: Did you use `<Card></Cade>` or `<Card></Card>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a typo in your code please check in Card component `{props.children}` not `{props.childern}`

Comment: I had figure that out already but forgot to update .Thank you